# Video player for Windows 10

Tags: windows, video, media-player

BS Player was my favorite media player, but after the last video driver update (or possibly Windows update) [it's messed up](https://superuser.com/questions/1127640/bs-player-video-play-back-not-showing-correctly-after-windows-update). Since the user community isn't very big it's hard to find information to fix problems with and I'd like a better supported and stable player. I would mainly use it for videos and would like it to be lightweight.

One thing I like about BS Player is it can automatically search for subtitles online, download and apply them. Also I like how the playback window is separate from the control bar.

Comment: Did you [search the site](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+video+player+subtitles)?

Comment: Can you clarify what "playback window is separate from the control bar" means?

Answer (score 3):

You should try and use the [VLC Media player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html).

> VLC is a free and open source cross-platform multimedia player and framework that plays most multimedia files as well as DVDs, Audio CDs, VCDs, and various streaming protocols.

Comment: Can VLC auto download subtitles?

Comment: A quick Google says that it can

Comment: @Mawg it relies on plugins and often the plugins are broken in updates.

Comment: This can occasionally happen to any program which accepts. I rollback to the previous version and contact the author of the plugin. I find them generally very keen to help.

Answer (score 0):

I was really big on BSplayer on my Android devices from Eclair or Froyo, don't remember right off. Tried the Win version, but didn't find it any better than VLC. I think the developers work more on the mobile side than on Windows, just from what I see. I kinda dropped BSplayer on the 'droids after VLC finally got there, and find that VLC and Media Player Classic do it for me on my Windows boxes, but I have simple media needs.